# Copy the values from variable cell values excel macro

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Please find the snapshot attched here with,

Snapshot show the A1 cell values varies from 1 to 19,

C1 contains the value which is vary fron number to number, i need row and columns of complete numbers and values.

like E and F columns indicate ( i have entered manually)

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that a user can enter a number between 1 and 19 into cel A1, and some value in C1? Or can the user enter numbers in column A, and values in column C?

Comment: user enter number between 1 to 19 in A1 and Values changes automatically in C1.

Answer (score 0):

Enter this formula into cel C1:

```
=VLOOKUP($A$1,$E$1:$F$19,2,FALSE)
```

It will look for the number you entered in A1 in column E, and return the corresponding value from column F.

Comment: No, I need E and F column values from A1 and C1

Comment: So you want column E filled from cell A1, and column F from cell C1. And you want cell C1 to change whenever cell A1 changes. So where is the new value of cell C1 supposed to come from, if it doesn't come from column F?

Comment: C1 value come from other formulae, Whenever A1 value changes C1 value cahnges. I need E filled with all A1 value list and F from cell C1.

Comment: I think you'll need to show some effort here. Which parts have you completed so far? And do you need help for (1) firing your macro whenever the values in cell C1 changes? Or do you need help with (2) some difficult part of your macro? Or do you need help with (3) defining the functionality of your macro?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will do what you expect:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'The sheet where you have to enter your data
For i = 1 To 19
    ws.Range("A1").Value = i 'change the value of A1 from 1 to 19 in a loop
    ws.Cells(i, 5).Value = i 'write the value in the sheet Result
    ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = ws.Range("C1") 'get the calculated value from C1
Next i
End Sub
```